# Problem with firebase functions: different output with emulator mode and deployment mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I dev this simple function using firebase functions, but I don't get the same output using the emulator and when I deploy the function

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const tiktokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');    


const getTrend = async (req, res) => {

    const data = []
    const posts = await tiktokScraper.trend('', { number: 5, noWaterMark: true });   

    for (let i = 0; i < posts.collector.length; i++) {       
        let message = posts.collector[i].text
        let videoUrl = posts.collector[i].videoUrl
        data.push({message, videoUrl})
    }
    
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data))

}

exports.fetchDatas = functions.https.onRequest(getTrend);
```

1. With the emulator, I do get my data.

```
[{"message":"Tiktok put it under review so here it is again :/ #CONO #rhythmicgymnastics","videoUrl":"https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/bfc6db42ee21e2a60a4ade97c6d74386/5f34ec73/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/0ee07996e83047edbca89a678e55c489/?a=1233&br=1520&bt=760&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020081107320301018919408142010730&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=ajxtbTV2a2RydTMzZjczM0ApO2Y0OmQ0Ojs3NzQ5Njg5OGdqaXAyMC01NHNfLS0yMTZzc141L2EvMl8xLV9gY2E2MzU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="},
{"message":"Anyone to challenge him #junya1gou #fyp","videoUrl":"https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/acb43d049db7527763618906798d303c/5f34ec73/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c001/b4aaaf3f8bae4fb2b15b9b4da1c539b2/?a=1233&br=1674&bt=837&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020081107320301018919408142010730&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=ajNkZm50cnE4djMzOTczM0ApZTc0MzdkNjtoNzplMzo0OWc1LS4xazFkcmtfLS0zMTZzcy0uLl42LjFeM2NjMjVjNV86Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="},
{"message":"What look do you prefer, first or second ?  Tenues 1 ou 2 ? @tiboinshape #foryou #pourtoi #mirrorchallenge","videoUrl":"https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/6bcdd615bb03a3daa0c43d06b1bcb129/5f34ec73/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/fc5bb5b337f245079b60d99c8937de7a/?a=1233&br=3224&bt=1612&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020081107320301018919408142010730&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=MzY6aWhtZ3k1dDMzNjczM0ApZWkzZjNmNGU1Nzw6ZGk0Omc1bi1ycWpsZHJfLS01MTZzcy1gYjRjYDAzMjUtM18tMDU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="},{"message":"","videoUrl":"https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/2c3e14224dd2653be091721efde8f707/5f34ec73/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/9cadcf3c058a4511b068b86f0cc52e3e/?a=1233&br=6302&bt=3151&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020081107320301018919408142010730&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=anBvODhtdTZpdTMzOzczM0ApO2g6NjtpOWU3NzQ1PGQzZGctNGZoNS5nZDJfLS01MTZzc2FgNV5hL2IvLzBhMC0wNDM6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="},
{"message":"Beatbox impossible ","videoUrl":"https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/72c9ed12ef5a468245e15b393162c1b5/5f34ec73/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/a504a07a22ed41b1884c31750b692f00/?a=1233&br=2214&bt=1107&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020081107320301018919408142010730&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=M3RmcnJyZWU2djMzPDczM0ApNmU6NWhpNWVkN2ZlOGc0N2dmY202anByb2VfLS1iMTZzczA1YDEvLjZgMDUxNS8xXjA6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr="}]
```

2. when i deploy the function, I just get an empty array

```
[]
```

Do you know why I don't get the same output ?

Cheers

Comment: Make sure you uploaded the data to Firebase.

Comment: I do not store anything as I am fetching data from an API. I'm only use the functions features allowing backend request.

Comment: Add logging to your function, does `posts` contain any data?